# Is there a specialized online medical dictionary for rare medical terms?

Tags: лексикон, перевод, resources

I have several rare medical terms I need to translate from English into Russian: Prolotherapy, Active Release Technique, Iontophoresis. Google translate doesn't help. Any good contemporary medical translator online?

Comment: I have such a lexicon for rare nuclear engineering terms, and so this question is interesting to me.

Answer (score 3):

Helas, there is a lack of such dictionaries covering all modern medical terms.
Sometimes following approach is helpful:

1. Searching for specific term in English Wikipedia (or any other wikipedia where the term can be find).
2. Clicking Russian in "Languages" section.

for example, [Iontophoresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iontophoresis) is [Ионоферез](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7)

Word translation can be found here - [lingvo.yandex.ru](http://lingvo.yandex.ru), but in you specific case this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Proloterapy seems to be translated as `Пролотерапия`. You can try to ask in active medical commuties, like http://doktor-killer.livejournal.com/